# Scattered line space is Paracompact

Tags: general-topology

Show that the Scattered line space is Paracompact ? that is for any open cover there is an open locally finite refinement.

Comment: Can you please remind us what the scattered line is?

Comment: The set is open in $S$ iff it is of the form $U \cup V$ where $U$ is an open subset of the real line with its usual topology and $V$ is any subsets of the irrationals. We call the resulting space $S$  the scattered line.

Comment: If $S$ is metric then $S$ is Paracompact. OR If $S$ is $T_{3}$ lindelof space , then it is Paracompact.

Comment: but I dont no whether $S$ is metric, lindelof, $T_{3}$

Comment: It is neither Lindelöf nor metrisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is more commonly called the Michael line $\mathbb{M}$, see [this blog post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/) for an online introduction. It has proofs that $\mathbb{M}$ is paracompact but not Lindelöf nor metrisable.

To see it is paracompact: take an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathbb{M}$ and we can assume WLOG that it consists of basic open subsets, so either Euclidean open, or singletons from the irrationals. Call the first subcollection of Euclidean open covering sets $\mathcal{U}’$ with union $Y$, then $\mathcal{U}’$ is a standard open cover of $Y$ (which is paracompact, being metrisable) so $\mathcal{U}’$ has locally finite (in the Euclidean sense) refinement $\mathcal{U}’’$. Then this collection together with all $\{x\}$, $x \notin Y$ is a locally finite open  refinement of $\mathcal{U}$. So $\mathbb{M}$ is paracompact.